# Account Payables for the same Partner in OpenERP

Tags: openerp-7

I'd like to know how I can utilize OpenERP fully in term of doctor commission payouts. Ideally, I'd like to know the breakdown of the commission of a doctor (from consultation / visiting in-patient / operation, etc).
An example:

The consultation fee is USD 100, the USD 60 will go as hospital income while the remaining USD 40 goes to the doctor as a commission fee.

From the above example I try to do it this way

I split the consultation fee to two products, Hospital Fee is USD 60 and the Doctor Fee is USD 40. For Hospital Fee I set the income account to "a hospital income", while Doctor Fee I set the income account to "a payable doctor fee". This way once the sale order is confirmed both income and payable accounts are updated correctly.

Issue:

With this method one doctor will have a lot of payable accounts (consultations / procedures / etc). I still can't figure out the way of performing payments to the doctor. I tried to setup the doctor as supplier, however the account payable can only be one for each supplier.

Anyone has any ideas on this ? Perhaps there's better way ? Thanks.